# Back up en postgres con un archivo .bat ¿Por que me genera el backup en blanco?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd, windows-server-2012, .bat

Hola a todos Tengo un script el cual me hace una copia de seguridad de mi base de datos, me funciona en mi local pero al momento de ejecutarlo en un servidor windows 2012 r2 me genera el archivo vacío. Este es mi guion:

```
  @echo on

    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
        set day=%%i
      set month=%%j
      set year=%%k
     )

    set datestr=%day%_%month%_%year%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
    echo datestr is %datestr%
    set BACKUP_FILE=C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\test/mibase_%datestr%.backup
    SET PGPASSWORD=1234
    echo on
    pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c base > %BACKUP_FILE% 
    SET PGPASSWORD=
```

Comment: Si corres manualmente ese pg_dump con esos parámetros (rremplazando la variable backup_file), funciona?

Comment: si en el local funciona y el server no, esta claro que es tema de ruta y/o permisos al momento de ejecutarse.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, si al correr pg_dump con esos parámetros funciona correctamente, el problema estaba en la ruta de pg_dump

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, dejo el ejemplo por si a alguien tiene el mismo problema:

```
@echo on

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
    set day=%%i
  set month=%%j
  set year=%%k
 )

set datestr=%day%_%month%_%year%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
echo datestr is %datestr%
set BACKUP_FILE=C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\test/mibase_%datestr%.backup
SET PGPASSWORD=1234
echo on
C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\bin\pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c base > %BACKUP_FILE% 
SET PGPASSWORD=
```